# Is it possible to force typecasting?

Tags: typescript

I'm consuming an API that exposes a method that may return an object from one of two different classes, let's say, `Car` or `Bike`. That is, the method would have the following signature:

`getVehicle(): Car | Bike`

Now let's say that in a specific case, I'm sure this method will return a `Car`, so I can call `getVehicle().fillTank()`, a method that's only available in `Car`. But TypeScript won't let me do this, since it thinks that this object may as well be a `Bike`, and in this case it wouldn't have a `fillTank()` method.

It won't let me cast to `Car` either, as in `const car: Car = getVehicle();` since some of `Car`'s properties are missing in `Bike`. Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: What is the specific case and how can you be sure it will return a Car? Can you represent that information in the type system (with overloads, discriminated union, etc) rather than trying to work around it?

Comment: You might be able to correlate the precondition with the result of the method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Safe way to do this is using [user defined type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards)

```js
function isCar(vehicle: Car | Bike): vehicle is Car {
  return (vehicle as Car).fillTank !== undefined
}

const vehicle = getVehicle()

if (isCar(vehicle)) {
  console.log(vehicle.fillTank)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using the `as` operator like this.

```
const car = getVehicle() as Car;
car.fillTank();
```